# How is damage of on-hit abilities (Mystic Shot, Parrrley, etc.) expressed?

Tags: league-of-legends

After reading [What can Pantheon's shield block?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112490/what-can-pantheon-shield-block), I found out that [on-hit effects](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effect) are still applied (such as [Teemo's Toxic Shot](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo#Toxic_Shot)) while the basic attack is blocked. This implies that the damage for such abilities is split into two parts: the damage of the basic attack itself and the damage from any on-hit effects. [Pantheon's passive](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Pantheon/Ability_Details) blocks the first part while the second part is unaffected.

As Teemo's on-hit effect is physical/magic damage split (physical for his basic attack and magic for his DoT), the concept is easy to picture. But, how does this apply to Gangplank's and Ezreal's Qs ([Parrrley](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gangplank#Parrrley) and [Mystic Shot](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ezreal#Mystic_Shot), respectively). Each of these abilities tack on additional physical damage, but is this considered an on-hit effect or simply a stronger basic attack? Additionally, how does this apply to items that add physical damage on-hit, such as [Blade of the Ruined King](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_of_the_Ruined_King)?

Comment: GP parrrley will be blocked, but the application of his passive won't.  Mystic shot damage will be blocked, but lets say you are rolling with IceBorn Gauntlets, the AoE slow will still proc.

Comment: @Brian I think you added too many links. The only really important link is to the reference question "What can Pantheon's shield block?". The rest of the links make his question hard to read because they are distracting and break reading stride; the terminology is also fairly well-known and easy to look up. I won't change it since I believe it's somewhat useful, but I think in general they should be used sparingly.

Comment: @SadlyNot One reason for the links is that they contain the answer to the question asked. Also because instead of opening a new tab searching for teemo's toxic shot and seeing the effects of it the visitor can simply ctrl-click :) Follows the concepts used on wikipedia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gangplanks and Ezreal's Q are both considered attacks (considered stronger basic attacks), so the entire attack is blocked, but any additional on hit effects should be applied then (eg. wits end)

Blade of the Ruined King's damage is an on-hit affect as well

Comment: Are there any other champions who have a similar dynamic with their skills or is it just GP and Ez?

Comment: There's more for sure ... off the top of my head, Trundle, Nasus ... Q's like that, they usually reset attack timer on melee

Comment: Furthermore, Gangplank's Parrrley is still treated as a melee attack. The utility tree mastery that gives gold on attack gives him 5 for it instead of the 3 that ranged attacks get.

Comment: @Yuuki Poppy is VERY different.  I believe her entire auto might actually go through his shield because it actually converts her auto into a 100% magical attack.  I'm not 100% sure on if it blocks part of the damage or not since it all becomes magical.